# Python 2.7 Boolean Operators Logic

Tags: python-2.7, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am currently in the course of learning Python 2.7 and have come across the Equality and Boolean operators

**My question is:**

Why `False and 1` is `False` but `True and 1` is `1`

Likewise, `False or 1` is `1` but `True or 1` is `True`

Can someone kindly explain why this is happening

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**and** returns the first 'falsy' (False, zero, empty string or list, etc.) value it sees, or the final value if none were falsy.  Further values are not even evaluated, since they can't change the result.

**or** likewise returns the first 'truthy' (True, non-zero, non-empty string or list, etc.) value it sees (or the final one if there were none), and doesn't evaluate the rest.

This behavior is sometimes more convenient than strictly returning only True or False.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I was missing out on the fact that any number other than `0` can also be considered as `True`.

Comment: Btw, going by the above logic, why do you think `False or 0` returns `0`. In this case both of them are actually Falsies, isn't it?

Comment: @pb_ng Note that the answer does state for the case of `or`: "or likewise returns the first 'truthy' [...] value it sees (**or the final one if there were none**)". There are no true values in `False or 0`, so the last one, 0, is the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It helped!